# wiring location for unfinished shed

Tags: wiring, shed

Ive  been coming across conflicting  information about wiring in the inside of the shed, or more specifically  where to attach the cable. I was under the impression  that you should always follow the framework.
So when it comes to going across the  studs, would you  drill holes in the studs and feed  it through there,or you could you run it across the top plate then bring it down the studs, and if is the case would you still need to drill through that top place to feed the wire through,or can you go over the framework.? ( this is going to be a unfinished shed)

Also.. my  power cable is coming  straight from the main  panel outside ( not inside the house),,  so do i still need a main cut off  switch at the shed?

Answer (score 1):

To me that's a no-brainer, for several reasons. It's much better protected in the wall, and it's not in the way of shelving, cabinets, wall surfacing, etc.

The NEC requires that all cabling be out of harm's way. Most interpretations prohibit surface-mounting of wiring for that reason. I prefer to run cables through the rafters (over the wall), and then through the top plate(s) and down the side of a stud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need a disconnect at the building.  It does not need to be outside.

You can only have one electrical circuit to an outbuilding, so plan accordingly.  I.E. you can't just trench a second cable if you need more power.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question,,the disconnect is just a switch, or one of them grey boxes with the pull down lever?

Comment: @Jben04 You can use anything rated for the current. No need for it to be outdoors.  It needs to interrupt only the hot(s).

Comment: so basically a light switch  rated for 20 amp ( 20 is what the breaker is in the main box) ?

Comment: @Jben04 Yup, that'll do er.  On the other hand, if you were bring a 2-hot *multi-wire branch circuit* (giving two 20A sub-circuits in one circuit)  then you'd need a 2-pole switch, at that point a grey box would be the cheapest way.

Comment: If i just go with the one 20 amp circuit in, i can use a junction box to direct the wires where i need them..?  I have the light switch which is going to control the lights ( which will be plugged into receptacles in the rear of the shed.) also want a  2 set of receptacles on one side, then hoping to put a  outside weatherproof receptacle in also.
I can do that with one circuit or would it need to be a multi-wire branch circuit?

Comment: The wire i'm using would be 12/2  romex for inside and the direct burial for outside..(if thats any help)

Comment: You can do that with 1 circuit... a MWBC would just be a clever way to get an extra "circuit" for virtually no more work. (although a more complicated switch).